# Difference between Objective-C instance variables and properties

Tags: objective-c

When you do

```
myClass.m
@interface myClass {
   NSMutableArray   *myArray;

}
@end
@implement
.....
.....
```

What is the purpose when you are trying declare a variable like this. 
How it looks differently when you declare

```
myClass.h
@import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface myClass () <TableViewDataSource>
NSMutableArray *myArray

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: How about a better, descriptive title?

Comment: "Stupid but need to clear it up." Is a horrible title and "iphone" is a very vague description. If you want attention and answers, try posting something to where people know what they're getting into before clicking.

Comment: .. and even after clicking, I haven't got a clue what your question is _asking_. Can you take a stab at rephrasing the question?

Comment: sorry to confused. My question is what is a difference when you are declaring a var in header file (first way ) and declare a var in m file ( second way ).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first example is the declaration of an instance variable.

The second is using a property.

There are differences between the two.  For example, when using an instance variable, you have to write your own getters/setters.  With property, you do not.

There are more differences and great detail can be found here:  [Declared Properties Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW13)

---

Updated given changes to original question.

Assuming you're talking about the myArray variable, in the first example, you've declared myArray as an instance variable of a class.  To access it, you'd need to create an instance of the class.

In the second example, you've declared it as a global variable which by default has file scope.  That is to say, you could use it in any file which includes the myclass.h header, without the need to create an instance of the class.  However, you do have to be careful about including it in multiple files, or you could end up with multiple definition errors.

Comment: Are you sure he's asking about the difference between properties and ivars and not the difference between declaring ivars in the header v. declaring them in the implementation?

Comment: I am sorry I have just modified the content of a question. Can you take a look again. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this answer would rate two downvotes.  If I misunderstood his poorly phrased question, that's not a poor answer - perhaps just not applicable.  However, I did briefly explain some of the difference between an ivar and property as well as linking to the documentation.

Comment: @wadesworld :thanks for your updated answer. I got the idea about these declarations now.

Comment: @wadesworld : i forgot to ask one thing and it seems important though. does it sound singleton when we are following the second declaration above because we are now invoking myArray without any instance of myClass like myClass.myArray. Pls correct me if i've made a mistake

Comment: @tonytran in the second instance, you do have a single variable, but that's not a singleton.  A singleton is a specific design pattern for ensuring only one of a particular type of object is instantiated.

Comment: sorry to get back to you lately....i got the idea now after reading some materials and based on what you gave me...Now I can see that the first one is to create a private variable so that you are going to limit the access to it from outside. Please correct me if I am wrong